# writing a method for fibonacci sequence

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a for loop that calls the method fibonacci and prints the first 25 numbers in the fibonacci sequence. The problem is I'm a little confused about how to do that correctly. 
 
 I'm a little confused about when the for loop in the run method calls the fibonacci method do the values inside the fibonacci method reset after reach pass of the for loop? So for example during the first pass of the for loop i = 0 and the values for int a and int b change inside the the fibonacci method. Do the values inside the fibonacci method reset on the next pass of the for loop?

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Fibonacci extends ConsoleProgram{
private void run(){

  for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
    fibonacci(i);
    println(fibonacci(i));
   }


}
 private int fibonacci(int n){
   int n = 0;

   int a = 0; 
   int b = 1;

   while (n < 25);

   int c = a + b;
   a = b;
   b = c;

     }
   return(a);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping in *two* different places - `run()` and `fibonacci()`.  Only one of these places should care about the loop, and the other should care about computing Fibonacci(n).

What we can do remove the loop from `fibonacci`, and only rely on the loop on the outside.  Also, we're going to remove that statement `int n = 0`, since that shadows the parameter you're passing in.

Lastly, we're going to create two new static variables `a` and `b`, so that the values of those are preserved with this instance.  If you don't do that, then you'd have to rely on either recursion or some other methodology to provide the appropriate values of `a` and `b`.

I'm not entirely sure why you need to extend `ConsoleProgram`, but I'll leave it in for now.

So, here's what it should look like.

```
public class Fibonacci extends ConsoleProgram {
    static int a = 0;
    static int b = 1;

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
            // Print the call to fibonacci(i) with every iteration.
        }
    }

    private int fibonacci(int n) {
        int c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: @makote You're saying have one part of the program focus on the loop and have the other part of the program concentrate on calculating for fibonacci? I'm confused where is the loop?

Comment: The loop belongs in `run`.  Essentially, the body of the loop changes to only contain the `System.out.println(fibonacci(n))`.

Comment: is the for loop in my question still being incorporated in your answer? If it is,  are static int a = 0; and static int b = 1; inside the for loop? Sorry I'm this is a stupid question, I'm just still a little bit confused.

Comment: I'll go ahead and clarify my answer a little bit more.

Comment: thanks for the clarification and thanks for taking the time to help me solve the problems I was having with the question.

Comment: When i got home and studied your example in depth i discovered that the program in your example skips the first two 0, 1 in the Fibonacci sequence and starts 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13... and so on. If it's not too much trouble how would the fibonacci sequence be calculated solely within the fibonacci method without using static variables?

Comment: In a word:  recursively.  There are ways to do it iteratively, but recursively would be the more intuitive approach.

Answer (score 1):

Fibonacci it's a typical example of an algorithm that can be easily approached with recursion, that's because:

- you can divide the entire fibonacci sequence in steps,
- in each step you have to do the same thing except for the final step where you got 0,
- and the last step is "special" because 0 times any number gives you 0,

so if you apply the same step as before you simply nullify everything, this means that when your counter is 0 you have to do something different from your previous steps and it's:

- multiply the result that you have stored by 1 and not by 0 ( or you can leave it as it is, it's the same thing as multiply by 1
- exit the loop and terminate the fibonacci sequence

Internet is full of Fibonacci examples, [1](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0100__Class-Definition/Recursivefibonaccimethod.htm) & [2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Fibonacci.htm) are more than enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

The variables reset for each iteration of the loop. The variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are local variables that only "live" within the method. Every call to the `fibonacci(n)` method should start from the beginning of the fibonacci sequence and print out the terms up until the nth term. Therefore, `while (n < 25);` should not be part of the method. Also, `int n = 0` resets n to zero, which is bad because we need to know what n is to get the nth term.

The ideal way to do this loop is:

```
private void fibonacci(int n) {
    int i = 1; // a new variable i to count from the 1st term
    int a = 0; // the first term
    int b = 1; // the second term

    while (i <= n) {
        int c = a + b; // the new value for b
        a = b; // switch the old a for the new a
        b = c; // get the (i + 1)th term for the next iteration
        System.out.println(a); // print out the ith term
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not storing the returned int value of fibonacci();

```
int currentSum=0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
currentSum+=fibonacci(i);
println(currentSum);
```

}

and why do you have another variable n in your fibonacci(int n) ?
Please make sure first your fibonacci method is working. (The infinite while loop, etc.)

```
public static void main (String args[]){
   for(int i = 0; i<25; i++) {
       System.out.println(fibonacci(i));  
   }

}

static int fibonacci(int n){
   if(n==0) {
       return 0;
   }
   int a = 0; 
   int b = 1;

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       int temp = b;
       b += a;
       a = temp;
   }

   return(b);
 }
```

Comment: do you mean int n = 0 at the top of the fibonacci method? That was a mistake